# Properties of Entity sent from iOS are set to null when objectify is used to store the entity into datastore

Tags: ios, entity, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I send an entity from an iOS client and it is processed by the following backendAPI method:

```
    @ApiMethod(name="dataInserter.insertData",path="insertData",httpMethod="post")
    public Entity insertData(customEntity userInput){
        ofy().save().entity(userInput).now();
        return userInput;
    }
```

customEntity is defined within customEntity.java as follows:

```
    //Import Statements here

    @Entity
    public class customEntity {
        @Id public String someID;
        @Index String providedData;
    }
```

After the above code runs, datastore contains the following entry:

```
    ID/Name      providedData
    id=5034...   <null>
```

If I add the following lines to my method:

```
    customEntity badSoup=new customEntity();
    badSoup.providedData="I am exhausted";
    ofy().save().entity(badSoup).now();
```

I see the following in the datastore after I run the code:

```
    ID/Name      providedData
    id=5034...   I am exhausted
```

In a post almost similar to this one, the poster -- Drux -- concludes "...assignments to @Indexed properties only have actual effects on indices (and hence queries) if they are carried out directly with Objectify on the server (not indirectly on iOS clients and then passed to the server with Google Cloud Endpoints)." stickfigure then responds, "It sounds like what you're saying is 'cloud endpoints is not reconstituting your SomeEntity object correctly'. Objectify is not involved; it just saves whatever you give it."

It's hard to tell whether stickfigure is correct most especially given the fact that when I explore my API using Google's APIs Explorer, the same problem described above still occurs.

Is anyone able to explain what's causing this or is Drux's conclusion correct?

Comment: Why don't you try logging the value of `userInput.providedData`  in `insertData()` and see for yourself?

Comment: Are you suggesting that a bug exists within the datastore that causes property values to disappear and be set to null when a request is made from the Google APIs Explorer and also when the same request is made from iOS? If so, is there a workaround to this problem?

Comment: I'm saying that Objectify (and everything else down the stack) saves what you give it. If you save an entity with a null `providedData` field, you'll get that value in the datastore. You can prove it to yourself with a simple debug statement. If you're finding unexpected null values in the datastore, look *up* the stack, not *down* the stack.

Comment: So anyway, the reason I chose to use objectify was so that I could create a custom entity and provide it with a constructor so that I could get rid of the error, "No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity]." I was successful but now my properties are empty. Is there a different way to get rid of this error without using objectify?

Comment: You might be able to transmit `Entity` with some sort of custom serialization; research the Cloud Endpoints protocol and tooling. No matter what you choose, be careful of letting users write any arbitrary entity into your datastore.